# How can i add custom field in customer address magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to add a field in customer address create and save into customer information how can i add this. 
[image]
i try this
http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html
but it make a field in Account information.

Comment: You want to display it on fronted customer address field right ?

Comment: yes, but it for later, now i want add a custom field in customer addresses in above image.

Comment: Check below my answer for reference.

Comment: let my try. :))

Comment: Have you try below solution ?

Comment: Are you sure, i tried but something wrong.

Comment: What is wrong with you ?

Comment: i make it, i must add "customer_address" in last of  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address','customer_address'],

Answer (score 7):

As per your reference example, attribute field will display in account information.

You have used **`Customer::ENTITY`** instead of '**customer_address**'

You can use below code for create customer address attribute, it will display in customer address.

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'magento_username', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Magento Username',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'magento_username')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
        ]);
```

It is use for display in admin and  fronted customer address form.

```
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
```

Let me know if you have any query from this.

Comment: can we show this directly in checkout too? What parameter should I add to used_in_forms to do so?

Comment: can we show this directly in checkout only shipping address?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a  field to the customer address involves creating a new customer address attribute (see eav_entity_type table), assigning that attribute to a form, and adding the  eld to the frontend.

Magento 2 does not automatically update the frontend customer  fields.

Again, keep in mind that customer and customer address attributes must be included in a form (customer_form_attribute table) so they can be saved.